# Spring Boot remove extra HealthIndicator information

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I just add a spring-boot-starter-actuator dependency to pom.xml of my application. After building and running project, /health endpoint showing the next information:

```
{
   "status": "UP",
   "details": {
       "application": {
           "status": "UP"
        }
    },
    "application": {
        "status": "UP"
    }
}
```

How can I remove the "details" section from response?

Comment: which Spring version are you using?! Any special things in your codes? Default one, it just shows the: {"status":"UP"}.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the root cause of the problem. It was incorrect configuration of MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter:

```
@Autowired
public void configureJsonSerializer(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter objectMapperBuilder) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
    objectMapperBuilder.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
}
```

The "details" field is private and stored in Health.class, but with this configuration it was added to final json response. I removed that and now everything works fine.

Comment: what was the version of spring you are using? I am seeing similar behavior in spring 2.1.3 and I have not defined any JSON serializer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57703224/spring-boot-2-1-3-remove-extra-details-field-from-custom-health-endpoint-resul. Any idea about this?